# 401 error with latest woocomerce api rest client for javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to learn how to use the api rest of woocommerce, I know it's working because I get a successful response in browser from

> wp-json/wc/v3/

The problem appears when I try get products or any route through the client library, for example:

```
const WooCommerce = new WooCommerceRestApi({
  url: "http://127.0.0.1/wordpress",
  consumerKey: "ck_1244aa98f0d30dc1cf077564e62dbf18cd516678",
  consumerSecret: "cs_32a45e80e2f1f159ee7ded559cc618e9ac8ffbdb",
  wpAPI: true,
  version: "wc/v3",
});

router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  WooCommerce.get("products")
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
      res.status(200).json(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error.response.data);
      res.status(400).json(error);
    });
});
```

So, this is the error message I receive

```
{
  "message": "Request failed with status code 401",
  "name": "Error",
  "stack": "Error: Request failed with status code 401\n    at createError (/home/micheln/Documentos/liderlogo/woocomerce-api/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)\n    at settle (/home/micheln/Documentos/liderlogo/woocomerce-api/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)\n    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/home/micheln/Documentos/liderlogo/woocomerce-api/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:236:11)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)\n    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)",
  "config": {
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-json/wc/v3/products",
    "method": "get",
    "params": {
      "oauth_consumer_key": "ck_1244aa98f0d30dc1cf077564e62dbf18cd516678",
      "oauth_nonce": "b4MP4qyo4MyXEFcEf6v8y5pAVq5x9Rq1",
      "oauth_signature_method": "HMAC-SHA256",
      "oauth_timestamp": 1580829128,
      "oauth_version": "1.0",
      "oauth_signature": "/X3pgZA+o/w5cS8Y3JV6HCkkD+0Nuc4uovkIMq8IC1o="
    },
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "User-Agent": "WooCommerce REST API - JS Client/1.0.1"
    },
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "timeout": 0,
    "responseType": "json",
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "responseEncoding": "utf8"
  }
}
```

We could say that I am a little, quite lost here. In the examples I've seen it works perfectly,

> [npm library link of latest version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api)

-

> [link to woocomerce docs rest api keys](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#rest-api-keys)

-

> [Link to products route in woocomerce api docs](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#products)

Comment: did you try the `Example for servers that not properly parse the Authorization header`?  http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?javascript#authentication-over-https on the right-side. It basically adds this parameter to WooCommerceRestApi init: `queryStringAuth: true`

Comment: I had already tried it, throw the same answer